# Windows 7 computer name changes on its own

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

I have a Dell Latitude D830 with Windows XP Professional that has been running on my local domain for many years.   I recently Installed Windows 7 Enterprise on the D830 using a brand new HDD so that I could still use XP if I needed to by just swapping out the HDD's.  I added the W7 installed system to my domain using a completely different machine name than that used for the XP system and everything seemed to be functioning as it should.

On boot up over the last two weeks or so I occasionally (three times now) get to the login screen and try to login to the domain only to get an error saying that the Computer name is not a trusted machine in the domain I'm trying to log in to.  I find out that the machine name on the W7 system has been changed somehow to that of my old XP system.

If on the W7 system I then change the name back to the correct name, disjoin the domain, reboot, add the machine back into the domain … all is well for an unknown period of time until this happens again.

This last time, I know for a fact that everything was fine the day before when I shut down the system.  I came in today, powered up the system and the machine name had been changed to that of my old XP system again.

Has anybody else seen this behavior or have any ideas on what could be causing it?

Comment: This sounds like your domain is assigning your MAC to a specific IP address, and when you swap the OS, the older name is cached in the DNS.

No, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Randolph.   

I could see the DNS issue being a problem with name resolution, but I have no idea how anything could be physically renaming the W7 machine.

Anyway... seems as though I may be the only one having this issue so I guess at this point I'll just have to live with it.

Thanks again.